# sympyの積分で、subsで後から代入の方法を教えて下さい。

Tags: sympy, 数学

subsで後から代入。計算2で、pi/2にならなくて、x変数が残ります。いい方法がありますか？

```
from sympy import *
var("x r")
f=sqrt(r**2-x**2)
print("計算1:r=r 面積=",integrate(f,(x,-r,r)))
print("計算2:r=1 面積=",integrate(f,(x,-r,r)).subs(r,1))
#
r=1
f=sqrt(r**2-x**2)
print("計算3:r=1 面積=",integrate(f,(x,-r,r)))
#
# 計算1:r=r 面積= Piecewise((Integral(Piecewise((-I*r/sqrt(-1 + x**2/r**2) + 3*I*x**2/(2*r*sqrt(-1 + x**2/r**2)) + I*x**2/(2*r*(-1 + x**2/r**2)**(3/2)) - I*x**4/(2*r**3*(-1 + x**2/r**2)**(3/2)), Abs(x**2/r**2) > 1), (r*sqrt(1 - x**2/r**2)/2 + r/(2*sqrt(1 - x**2/r**2)) - x**2/(2*r*sqrt(1 - x**2/r**2)), True)), (x, -r, r)), r > -r), (-Integral(Piecewise((-I*r/sqrt(-1 + x**2/r**2) + 3*I*x**2/(2*r*sqrt(-1 + x**2/r**2)) + I*x**2/(2*r*(-1 + x**2/r**2)**(3/2)) - I*x**4/(2*r**3*(-1 + x**2/r**2)**(3/2)), Abs(x**2/r**2) > 1), (r*sqrt(1 - x**2/r**2)/2 + r/(2*sqrt(1 - x**2/r**2)) - x**2/(2*r*sqrt(1 - x**2/r**2)), True)), (x, r, -r)), True))
# 計算2:r=1 面積= Integral(Piecewise((-I*x**4/(2*(x**2 - 1)**(3/2)) + 3*I*x**2/(2*sqrt(x**2 - 1)) + I*x**2/(2*(x**2 - 1)**(3/2)) - I/sqrt(x**2 - 1), Abs(x**2) > 1), (-x**2/(2*sqrt(1 - x**2)) + sqrt(1 - x**2)/2 + 1/(2*sqrt(1 - x**2)), True)), (x, -1, 1))
# 計算3:r=1 面積= pi/2
```

(参考)wolframalpha
Integrate[sqrt(r**2-x**2),{x,-r,r}]
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5Bsqrt%28r**2-x**2%29%2C%7Bx%2C-r%2Cr%7D%5D&lang=ja
定積分:
integral_(-r)^r sqrt(r^2 - x^2) dx = (π r^2)/2 ただし，r>0

Integrate[sqrt(1**2-x**2),{x,-1,1}]
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5Bsqrt%281**2-x**2%29%2C%7Bx%2C-1%2C1%7D%5D&lang=ja
定積分:
integral_(-1)^1 sqrt(1^2 - x^2) dx = π/2≈1.5708

Comment: `doit()` を使えばよいのではないでしょうか。`integrate(f,(x,-r,r)).subs(r,1).doit()`

Comment: doitで、できました。